# parse-server times out on role save

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-server

```
Parse.Cloud.define('assignRole', function(request, response){
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

var user = Parse.User.current();

var roleQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Role);
roleQuery.equalTo("name", "UserManager");

roleQuery.first({ useMasterKey: true }).then(function (role) {
    role.getUsers().add(user);
    return role.save();
}, function (error) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    response({success:false})
}).then(function (userRole) {
    if(userRole) {
        response({success:true})
    } else {
        response({success:false})
    }
});
});
```

Any ideas why? I get 504, and it always times out. What am I doing wrong?
Similar code works in afterSave.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:  If your roleQuery fails, you pass response.success. However, the way promises work, it's going to return an empty resolved promise that gets passed to the next link in the promise chain, so the success block of the last .then() handler will get called, and you'll get an error for calling response multiple times.

The other: You don't have an error handler in the second .then(), so my bet is that your role.save() is failing (permissions perhaps? try `role.save(null, {useMasterKey:true});`, and if that's the case, you never call response.error or response.success.